# expression evaluation with right-associativity in java

Tags: java

I am trying to solve a problem in which I have to solve a given expression consisting of one or more initialization in a same string with no operator precedence (although with bracketed sub-expressions). All the operators have right precedence so I have to evaluate it from right to left. I am confused how to proceed for the given problem. Detailed problem is given here : http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=108

Comment: word `right precedence` is incorrect.

Comment: it means expression will get evaluated from the right with no operator precedence.

Comment: can you not reverse the string? - if precedence makes no difference... unless the bracketting does matter... (make sure to respond with @d'alar'cop at the start)

Comment: Yes Abhay its understood, the correct word is `Right-to-left Associativity` or `simply Right-Associativity`, thought I think *right precedence*  shouldn't be wrong because if same operators in a expression then associativity decides which should perform first and due to Right-Associativity, right most operator has higher precedence.

Comment: @d'alar'cop: it also contains initialization of variables. See the link for the exact problem. So, I don't think reversing the entire string will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some ideas to try:

First off, you need to recursively evaluate inside brackets. You want to do brackets from most nested to least nested, so use a regex that matches brackets with no `)` inside of them. Substring the result of the computation into the part of the string the bracketed expression took up.

If there are no brackets, then now you need to evaluate operators. The reason why the question requires right precedence is to force you to think about how to answer it - you can't just read the string and do calculations. You have to consider the whole string THEN start doing calculations, which means storing some structure describing it. There's a number of strategies you could use to do this, for example:

-You could tokenize the string, either using a scanner or regexes - continually try to see if the next item in the string is a number or which of the operators it is, and push what kind of token it is and its value onto a list. Then, you can evaluate the list from right to left using some kind of case/switch structure to determine what to do for each operator (either that, or each operator is associated with what it does to numbers). `=` itself would address a map of variable name keys to values, and insert the value under that variable's key, and then return (to be placed into the list) the value it produced, so it can be used for another assignment. It also seems like `-` can be determined as to whether it's subtraction or a negative number by whether there's a space on its right or not.

-Instead of tokenization, you could use regexes on the string as a whole. But tokenization is more robust. I tried to build a calculator based on applying regexes to the whole string over and over but it's so difficult to get all the rules right and I don't recommend it.

I've written an expression evaluating calculator like this before, so you can ask me questions if you run into specific problems.

Comment: I started by storing string characters in a stack, now i am trying to define every possible outcome after popping the stack one by one.

Comment: @Abhay Don't store EVERY character in a stack - use a scanner or regular expressions to determine the semantic type of the next token in the string (is it a number? What is its value? Is it an operator?) And create some kind of class system to encapsulate the information about each token. Then create a list holding all the tokens as you find them. If that's what you meant, then ok :D